# Does Xamarin.mac Support GTK# User Interface

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, xamarin.mac

I have an application coded with Mono.Mac using GTK# for the UI.I now have access to Xamarin.mac.Im trying to migrate the mono.mac solution to xamarin.mac. I'm trying copy-paste the code from mono.mac to a new xamarin.mac project,but there is no GUI builder in the Xamarin.mac project.So does Xamarin.mac support GTK#? Is there a better way i can migrate?

***EDIT:***

My goal is to bundle the mono runtime with the app package so that the user need not install it manually.

Comment: MonoMac and Xamari.Mac emphasize on Cocoa, so it would be weird to use GTK#.

Comment: @LexLi well if you download xamarin studio free(Mono.mac) version you only find option to create a GTK# app

Comment: Migrate? Do you mean converting your GTK# interface to Native OS-X via XWT or Cocoa or just using your Xam.Mac license to create a self-contained app bundle. If just the app bundle, when you open your monomac project and you have the option to convert it to Xam.Mac which updates the project guid (backup your project first so you have the old guids so monomac would still be an option if needed). Nothing else needs to change unless you are also migrating your code base to the Unified OSX/iOS api.

Comment: You should make yourself aware of the difference among Xamarin Studio, MonoMac, and Xamarin.Mac. I can see you simply misunderstood all of them and they are not interchangeable.

Comment: @RobertN Yeah, i mean converting Mono.Mac project to Xam.mac.My only intention is to bundle the mono runtime with application and create a self contained app bundle for apple store.The program UI is designed in GTK# i dont want to create it again for xamarin.mac using XCODE.I tried opening the mono.mac project using licensed Xamarin Studiod(with xamarin.mac installed),but there was no option shown to convert it.

Comment: Normally you get a 'Convert' dialog box the first time you open the project and have an option to Convert it or not (and suppress future prompts)... But you can also do it from the Project menu. Highlight the project file, goto Project in the Main Menu and the last item should be "Migrate to Xamarin.Mac" Bundling options should now be enabled...

Comment: @RobertN Thanks but i cannot find that in the Project Menu.

Answer (score 1):

MonoMac .csproj information:

First if you are not getting the upgrade to Xam.Mac dialog, it could be due to one or both of the following lines in your MonoMac project file:

```
<SuppressXamMacUpsell>True</SuppressXamMacUpsell>
<SuppressXamMacMigration>True</SuppressXamMacMigration>
```

If they exist, just edit the csproj file (right-click on project file: select Tools/Edit file), delete those lines, and save the file which should case an auto-project refresh, if no, close and reopen the solution/project.

Of course this assumes that the project is tagged as a **MonoMac Type project** in the csproj file.

At this point I would assume your project was originally created as a normal .Net project and you manually added MonoMac as a reference and thus XamStudio and xbuild would not see it as a 'special project type'.

Look for the ProjectTypeGuids tag in the project file:

The following is a C# / MonoMac project:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{948B3504-5B70-4649-8FE4-BDE1FB46EC69};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Assuming you only find the C# tag and not the MonoMac/Xam.Mac tag, I would change the project type and add MonoMac and then allow XamStudio to convert it to Xamarin.Mac (really just updating the guid and the MonoMac reference to XamMac)..

Current project:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Edit to:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{948B3504-5B70-4649-8FE4-BDE1FB46EC69};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

After XamMac conversion:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B 00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

At this point, your project should be seen as a XamMac type and the bundling from the menu, extra project options, etc. should now be exposed.

Standard C#/.Net project tag:

```
{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
```

Xamarin.Mac project tag:

```
{42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23}
```

MonoMac project tag:

```
{948B3504-5B70-4649-8FE4-BDE1FB46EC69}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer.Just to clarify i had created the project using the Project>.NET>GTK#2.0 Project.Is this Mono.mac? Totally confused at this point.

Comment: No, a GTK#2 project is not a MonoMac project. Not sure if a 'GTK' project actually has a unique project guid... hmmm.. create one via the project wizard and check the csproj file for a ProjectTypeGuids tag. Now that I thinking about it, i wondering if XS/xbuild works in this project combination in order to use the bundling features. I know you can reference/use MonoMac/Xam.Mac apis in a GTK# app but you would be reversing that in order to get the bundling features... Well, create a test solution/project and change it to a MonoMac project, convert it to XamMac and see if it works....

Comment: it has a GUID.I will try to replace it with Mono.mac GUID then convert it to Xam.mac and get back to you.I dont have the Mac with me right now.

Comment: I had put in some real hard work to design the GTK# Interface(you had helped me on SO with some of my questions).The app is almost ready and i was going to test it.But now comes the issue of bundling the Mono Runtime.Do you think if put in the extra work to create the cocoa interface in a new Xamarin.Mac project and copy all the code from GTK# project.Will i benefit in someway?

Comment: I tried changing the GUID to Mono.Mac but the project still opened up as GTK# App.