# I get "the application has not been built" from Visual Studio 2019 on Mac for Xamarin.IOS app project. Target is iphone, not sim

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Project was copied over from a VS on Windows, on which it builds and runs okay through same Mac, onto an iPhone.

I just installed VS on the Mac.
Anything special on it I need to do?

Comment: have you tried rebuilding it?

Comment: Try to delete the bin and obj folder, then clean and rebuild again.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer or write your own if the issue has been resolved

Comment: You might want to upgrade your project to Xamarin.Mac, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423984/does-xamarin-mac-support-gtk-user-interface for guidance (adding "{42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23}").
Maybe that might help? (blind shot)

Answer (score 1):

Check for the default project selected to build & deploy.

Often when switching projects from Windows to Mac the default deploy project is selected as Droid. The same is for vice versa when switching projects from Mac to Windows the default deploy project is selected as iPhone.

If the problem still persists try to -

- Try deleting the packages folder containing nuggets.
- Restore nugget packages.
- Clean & Rebuild Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Delete the Bin and Obj folder.
- Clean the solution
- Rebuild the solution
- In the top left hand corner choose Ad-Hoc|iPhone if you have this option

  - If not select debug | iPhone

Answer (score 0):

In the "Solution" pane, check if any of your projects have a blue info icon next to them that, when hovered over, display "Project not built in active configuration".  If so, you might have to try the following to add them to the build:

1. In the Solution pane, Control+Click on the root project > Options.
2. In the Solution Options popup, expand "Build" on the left (if needed) and select "Configurations" below it.
3. On the right, switch to the "Configuration Mappings" tab.
4. Add a check to the box in the "Build" column for any Solution Item that needs to be part of your build.  Set the drop down in the "Configuration" column to the appropriate value (guessing "Debug|iPhone" since it sounds like you were trying to test on an actual iPhone, not the simulator).
5. Click "OK" to close the Solution Options popup.
6. Build menu > Clean All.  Build menu > Rebuild All.
7. Try running the project again, either with the "Play" arrow in the header or the Run menu > Start debugging.

The steps above were generated using Visual Studio for Mac Professional, v8.10.6 (build 10).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, but it was a clean/new project.
In project's Options, under Build/Mac Signing, I checked 'Sign the application bundle; and selected the 'Mac Developer (Automatic)' identity.